# ¿Cómo obtener el registro anterior de una consulta SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Estoy realizando un sistema en el cual el usuario debe completar ejercicios para avanzar al siguiente nivel, lo que necesito es realizar una consulta SQL para obtener el id del ejercicio anterior, hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
SELECT  *,
LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY `parent_id` ASC, `orden` ASC) AS Anterior
FROM categorias
WHERE oculto is NULL AND es_ejercicio=1
```

De esa forma funciona correctamente, el problema es que trae todas las filas y yo necesito información solo sobre 1 fila en particular, es decir, que agrego por ej:

```
AND Id=12
```

Y me trae la fila en particular pero la columna "Anterior" ya me aparece NULL. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?. Gracias!

Comment: Por favor muestra un pequeño extracto del set de datos, dinos qué manejador de BD usas y dinos qué hay sobre el orden en que vienen o deben venir los datos.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, estoy usando Mariadb, lo que yo necesito es solo saber el Id de un regiostro anterior. Es probale que el metodo que este utilizando no sea el correcto, porque no se como se deberia hacer. Gracias

Comment: Puedes intentar algo así más o menos: `SELECT Id, @a := @a + Id 
    FROM categorias JOIN (SELECT @a := 0) t WHERE es_ejercicio=1` quizá tengas que ordenar o no, según qué datos tengas en la tabla.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, no estoy familiarizado con @a := @a + Id jejej me devuelve unos numeros pero no se que son. Gracias!

Comment: SUgerencia: las preguntas sobre SQL deben siempre incluir la definición de las tablas involucradas y algún conjunto de datos de prueba para entender qué quieres obtener y qué está obteniendo tu consulta actual

Comment: Ahí `@a` es una variable que en cada fila irá siendo sumada al valor de `Id` para poder determinar así el valor anterior de la columna. En cualquier caso deberías mostrar un pequeño dataset con valores de ejemplo y otro con los valores que esperas.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero esta solución para el `Id=3`:

```
SELECT Id FROM categorias WHERE orden=(
  SELECT MAX(orden) FROM categorias WHERE
    orden<(
      SELECT orden FROM categorias WHERE Id=3
    )
    AND oculto is NULL AND es_ejercicio=1
  );
```

Con el dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE categorias(
  Id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id int,
  orden float,
  oculto bool,
  es_ejercicio bool
  );
INSERT INTO categorias (parent_id,orden,es_ejercicio) VALUES
  (NULL,1,1),
  (1,2,1),
  (1,3,1),
  (2,4,1);
```

Obtendrías:

> 2

Aunque, como ordenas por dos campos, me da la sensación de que no te va a resolver todos los casos. Si estoy en lo cierto, añadiría un campo `ordenacion` en el que, antes de realizar la consulta, asignara el verdadero orden de cada registro y, entonces, utilizaría la misma consulta sustituyendo `orden` por `ordenacion`.

Sería algo así:

```
ALTER TABLE categorias ADD ordenacion int;

set @orden=0;
UPDATE categorias set ordenacion=(@orden:=@orden+1)
  ORDER BY parent_id,orden;
```

Con una consulta así:

```
SELECT Id FROM categorias WHERE ordenacion=(
  SELECT MAX(orden) FROM categorias WHERE
    ordenacion<(
      SELECT orden FROM categorias WHERE Id=3
    )
    AND oculto is NULL AND es_ejercicio=1
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

agrega  todas las filas a un tabla temporal y luego fíltrala por id

```sql
create procedure Anterior

@id int

as

CREATE TABLE #temporal

(
Id INT,

Anterior int

)

insert into #temporal(Id,Anterior)

SELECT Id,

LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY Id asc, id_pago ) AS Anterior

FROM pago_paradero

WHERE oculto is NULL AND es_ejercicio=1


select anterior from #temporal

where id=@id
```